# Trigger doesn't work at all

Tags: mariadb, database-trigger

I have these tables: `Attendence(id,start_time as TIME,end_time as TIME)` and `editattendencerequest(id,attendence_id,new_start_time,new_end_time,status as ENUM('Approved','Rejected','Pending')`

Now when an edit request is approved by updating its status I want the database to automatically update the specified attendence's start_time and end_time to new_start_time and new_end_time.

I defined this triger through phpmyadmin:
[image]

And here is the trigger in code :

```
IF NEW.status <> OLD.status THEN
    IF NEW.status = 'Approved' THEN
        UPDATE attendence set start_time = NEW.start_time and end_time=NEW.end_time where id = NEW.attendence_id;
    END IF;
END IF
```

Yet when I insert an attendence, insert an edit request and then update its status to Approved all through phpmyadmin I don't see the attendence updated at all.

So why isn't it working ? and how to make it work ?

My OS is windows 7 and using xampp 7.1.11.

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714) Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

Comment: @Rob I edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `and` word in the `SET` portion of the UPDATE is the issue. The fields in the SET portion should be separated by commas, try this instead:

```
IF NEW.status <> OLD.status THEN
    IF NEW.status = 'Approved' THEN
        UPDATE attendence 
           SET start_time = NEW.start_time, end_time = NEW.end_time
         WHERE id = NEW.attendence_id;
    END IF;
END IF
```